# Opening '.txt' Files in Python

Tags: python, file-io, text-files

**Answer Has Been Decided**

```
The problem was not listing the entire file listing (i.e. DRIVE1\DRIVE2\...\fileName.txt).
Also, note that the backslashes must be turned into forwardslashes in order for
Python to read it (backslashes are outside of the unicode listing).
Thus, using: addy = 'C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/Python/newfile.txt'
      returns the desired results.
```

It's been a while since I have played with **Python**, and for my most recent class, we are required to make a BFS search that does a **Word Puzzle** that the *Alice in Wonderland* author created. I am just stating this, as the algorithm is the homework, which I have completed. In other words, my question does not apply to the answer to my homework question.

With that out of the way, I am in need of help on how to open, edit, read, create some form of text files in Python. My real problem is to place a list of words that I have inside of a .txt file, into a Dictionary [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary). but I would much rather do this myself. Thus, I am left with how to do the said to text files.

**NOTE**:

```
 I am running v3.3. 
 All documentation that I have found while searching how to solve this simple problem
      is in regards to 2.7 or older.
```

I have tried to use:

```
>>> import sys from argv
>>> script, filename = argv
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
       script, filename = argv
    ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I have also tried to use:

```
>>> f = open(newfile.txt, 'r')
```

But again, I get this error:

```
 File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
        f = open (filename, 'r')
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'newfile.txt'
```

However, I am positive that this file does exist. All of this being said, I am not sure if this is a directory problem, a problem understanding, or what... That is, anything would help!

Comment: Use quotes for your filename.

Comment: and `from sys import argv`

Comment: Aslo, @Eric Fortin, the same exact error as the last one in my OP comes up while trying to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to retrieve a file name which is passed as the first argument to your script, use code like this:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    # set a default filename or print an error
```

Secondly, the error clearly indicates that the script can't find the file `newfile.txt`. So it is either not in the current directory, you don't have the permission to read it, etc...

Comment: check out the in-built python libraries argsparse (or getopt or optparse) if you want funky command line argument handling.

Comment: I did the import code (@Mhlester, I realized I added an 's' at the end, sorry), and I return filename = 'newfile.txt'. But I am still having a problem opening it. Does this have to be saved in a certain place (i.e. my file needs moved / directory needs changed)? Right now, the file I am trying to read is in a folder, and the folder is on my desktop (windows 8.1 user).

Comment: try using the full path to the file, i.e. DRIVE:/DIR1/DIR2/FILENAME, or `cd` to the folder where the file resides before running the script.

Comment: @isedev, I did the above in the form of **addy = 'C:\Users\Tanner\Desktop\Python\newfile'** and returned an unicode error. I also tried the above with double quotes, and received exactly the same error. Lastly, what do you mean by **cd**?

Comment: Use forward slashes '/' within Python (it will translate accordingly). Backslashes '\' have a special meaning... `cd` = change current directory command (when running stuff from a command.exe shell).

Comment: I switched it to **addy = 'C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/Python/newfile.txt'**, and it looks like it is working now! At least, I returned something that wasn't coated in red :p

Comment: @isedev, as I have been helping some new users on SO with their problems, I wanted to personally thank you again for taking your time out to help me solve my problem, when I was a new user.

Comment: you're very welcome, I'm glad you've decided to be active in the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file for reading, use with command as follows

```
# This is python 3 code
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

with command used together with open command has already the raising exception process.